# File path when working with One Drive for Buisiness

Tags: c#, ms-word, onedrive

I have a MS Word Add-In that works with a file located in the local synchronized area of One Drive for Business.

I create the file at C:..\OneDrive..\MyDir\File.docx
Some point later I create a FileInfo object:

```
var file = new FileInfo(doc.FullName);
```

This works fine when I debug. However when I run the code normally, doc.FullName is the web path https://..-my.sharepoint.com/personal/../MyDir/File.docx
Which breaks the FileInfo object.

Why would MS Word return the uri instead of the local file path?
and why is MS Word inconsistent when debugging my add-in?
and any thoughts on whether I can code around this?

-- Edit --

There are three behaviours:

1. Run Winword.exe (doc.FullName = http://[OneDrive])
2. Run Winword.exe and attach to process in Visual Studio (doc.FullName = http://[OneDrive])
3. Press F5 in Visual Sudio to debug (doc.FullName = C:..\OneDrive..)

Comment: have you tried to run the application \ exe and then attach visual studio to that process to see where it it picks things up from and then debug it this way?

Comment: Interesting.. When I attach the debugger to Winword.exe the doc.FullName is the web path http:// (will update the post above). I wonder why it's different when Visual Studio starts Winword.exe via F5??

Comment: Whats the full path of the file when you run it from VS?

Comment: The local path to my One Drive folders - C:\Users\<User>\OneDrive - <Org>\MyDir\

Comment: is that what you see when you debug through VS?

Comment: Yes. But only when I press F5 and cause VS to start Winword.exe

Comment: I'm not able to repro that behavior. Are you certain that everything is exactly the same? Or could it be that in one scenario the file is created and saved to the local sync folder (and hence is not synched yet and has a local filename) whereas in the other scenario the file has already been syched?

Comment: Interesting.. Yes, I created the file in the local folder, so it's possible that it hadn't synced yet. I'll do some more testing.

Answer (score 2):

Word can open both local files and cloud files. When the latest OneDrive sync client is installed and you open a local file that's sync'd to the cloud, Word will discover its cloud URL and prefer using that, because it lights up cloud-based features like coauthoring. If it's possible for your plugin to be tweaked to support cloud-only files that don't have a local copy, then that solution will probably work for OneDrive-sync'd file as well.

Comment: I had many discussions around this with the Office PG as this is not what people expect. You see the same thing if you in Word (desktop) manually goto File - Open File Location. That opens the 'online' document location instead of the local file location. Desktop users expect to go to the local location instead.

Comment: Any news here? I face the same issue. Is it not possible to get the proper local folder instead of getting the remote Synced one? No property, no other possibility to get somehow this value?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer on this link:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1331519b-1dd1-4aa0-8f4f-0453e1647f57/how-to-get-physical-path-instead-of-url-onedrive?forum=officegeneral

```
        private string GetFileLocalPath(string rawPath)
        {
            try
            {
                var workbookUri = new Uri(rawPath);
                // If local file, return it as-is
                if (workbookUri.IsFile)
                    return rawPath;

                string localPath = string.Empty;
                // Registry key names to loop                
                List<string> keyNames = new List<string>() { "OneDriveCommercial", "OneDrive", "onedrive" };
                foreach (var keyName in keyNames)
                {
                    using (var key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Environment", false))
                    {
                        var rootDirectory = key.GetValue(keyName).ToString();
                        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(rootDirectory) == false && System.IO.Directory.Exists(rootDirectory))
                        {
                            var pathParts = new Queue<string>(workbookUri.LocalPath.Split('/'));
                            do
                            {
                                // Compose a local path by adding root directory and slashes in between                                
                                string subPath = string.Join("\\", pathParts);
                                localPath = string.Format("{0}{1}", rootDirectory, subPath);

                                if (System.IO.File.Exists(localPath))
                                    return localPath;

                                // The file was not found - get rid of leftmost part of the path and try again
                                pathParts.Dequeue();
                            }
                            while (pathParts?.Count() > 0);

                        }
                    }
                }
                return localPath;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                return rawPath;
            }

        }
```

Comment: Let me put a warning on my own answer: it doesn't work for sharepoint site (which ends up in one drive). To reproduce: go to a sharepoint library and click "Synchronize". This will create a new "one drive" folder in windows explorer. The code above doesn't work if document is opened from this location